# Primitive Recursive functions

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to define some [basic Primitive Recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Definition) functions in Haskell. Why is my `times` function recursing one too many times (ie `eval times[x,y]` is resulting in `(x+1)*y`)? I think my problem is generally due to a poor understanding of how the Composition function works. Please don't give an answer without an explanation to clarify my understanding.

```
 import Prelude hiding (pred,and,or,not)

 data PR = Z
         | S
         | P Int
         | C PR [PR]
         | PR PR PR
         deriving Show
 eval :: PR -> [Integer] - Integer
 eval Z _ = 0
 eval S [x] = x+1
 eval (P n) xs = nth n xs
 eval (C f gs) xs = eval f (map (\g -> eval g xs) gs)
 eval (PR g h) (0:xs) = eval g xs
 eval (PR g h) (x:xs) = eval h ((x-1) : eval (PR g h) ((x-1):xs) : xs)

 nth _ [] = error "nth nil"
 nth 0 _ = error "nth index"
 nth 1 (x:_) = x
 nth (n) (_:xs) = nth (n-1) xs

 one = C S [Z]
 plus = PR (P 1) (C S [P 2])
 times = PR (P 1) (C plus [P 2, P 3])
```

I've tried a few other things for `times` the closest being `times = PR (P 1) (C plus[P 2, P 2]` but this comes out to `2x*y` I thought "Well I'll just replace one of those `P 2`'s with `Z` and then it will be `x*y`" This actually makes it the identity function of `y` and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definition for times seems to work:

```
times' = PR Z (C plus [P 2, P 3])

*Main> eval times' [6,7]
42
```

This makes sense since 0*x = 0 not 1.

Note that I had to change the definition of `eval (C ...)` in order for it to compile:

```
eval (C f gs) cs = eval f (map (\g -> eval g cs) gs)
```

More detailed explanation...

We know that `times` will be of the form `PR Z h` for some `h`.

Let's expand `eval (PR Z h) (x+1:y:ys)` ...

```
eval (PR z h) (x+1:y:ys)
    = eval h ((x+1-1) : eval (PR g h) ((x+1-1):y:ys) : y : ys)
    = eval h (x : eval (PR Z h) (x:y:ys) : y : ys)
    = eval h (x : x*y : y : ys)
```

because by induction we know `eval (PR z h) (x:y:ys) = x*y`.

So what does `h` have to be in order to get `(x+1)*y = y+x*y`? We need to add `y` (which is `P 3`) and `x*y` (which is `P 2`), so we should define `h` as:

```
h = C plus [P 2, P 3]
```

If you use `P 1` instead of `Z`, then your base case is `y` and not `0`:

```
eval (PR (P 1) ...) (0:y) = eval (P 1) (y) = y
```

The recursion stays the same, so you're off by `y` in your answer.

Comment: That was a typo in `eval (C....)`. Can you further explain why his works? It does make sense to me that `Z` should be there somewhere but why in place of `P 1`? Also, I don't exactly understand how `P 3` maps to the input. Times is being passed two values, where does the third come from?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose `op` is of the form `PR something (C otherThing projections)`. Then, if `x > 0`,

```
eval op [x,y]
```

calls

```
eval (C otherThing projections) [x-1, (x-1) `op` y, y]
```

The `otherThing` is the operation the higher-ranked `op` is composed from. And in the simpler cases, you want to invoke that only on the result `` (x-1) `op` y `` of the recursive call and `y`, so the projections should select the second and third element of the argument list.

Hence we have

```
times = PR something (C plus [P 2, P 3])
```

since we have the recursive equation

```
x*y = (x-1)*y + y
```

which doesn't involve an isolated `x-1`.

Now, when the base case `x == 0` is reached, the recursive call should return the base result. For multiplication, that is of course 0, thus the `something` should be `Z`, independent of `y`, and not `y` which `P 1` would give you.

Therefore, as [user5402 said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13547387/1011995), you should have

```
times = PR Z (C plus [P 2, P 3])
```